# OpenSuse won't boot after Windows install

Tags: windows, linux, boot, grub, opensuse

I have OpenSuse 11.4 running and I just installed Windows 7 in the same HDD on some extra space. Windows killed grub (I knew it would) so I put in my grub cd and selected "Detect any OS". It took a second and found my new windows installation along with my Opensuse (one option was single user mode, the other was just normal).

When I selected the regular opensuse install, all I get is a nice looking terminal thingy with suse's logo in the background and I get a login prompt (command line login, no gui). So my first problem is that -- I can't get the GUI to work.

Also, when I try to login at the prompt I get this error:

Error in service module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, comment out the last three lines of /etc/pam.d/login and see what it does. That's probably where the error message is coming from.

Comment: Thanks for the help, now I'm able to login through the command line. But I still can't do anything -- the filesystem seems to be mounted in read-only mode. Could this be because GRUB installed? Does grub handle fs mounting?

Comment: How did you install grub? Did you use something like the Super Grub2?

Comment: Actually I resolved the issue. Everything was around me not having grub. I was able to drop to a root shell with an old grub repair disc and rebuild grub.

Comment: good to hear :)